Picture storage rest service
I'm trying to find some software that I could use to store and retrieve pictures. I think its rather simple but I'm not quite finding a good candidate.
The idea is calling this picture service using a REST interface: some privileged users could post pictures using a POST HTTP request, and any anonymous user could retrieve those pictures with a GET HTTP request.
I will add this service to a docker-compose file along with a web server and database, so It would be great if it includes docker support.
Any bonus features such as galleries, compression, etc. are welcome but at the very least I need storage an retrieval.

Who is priviledged user? Someone with a token? Or do you need an entire login system?

@Destroy666 any of those options are fine.

You could try Uploady which is a PHP app to upload images.

It has user/role management as one of the futures, which would limit who can upload. I'm not sure if that works with API though, which only lists X-API-KEY header auth. It also has some Docker image and docker-compose support.
